# Duplicate meta description

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, meta-description

I am having an issue with one of the websites.

Google is reporting that I am having duplicate meta descriptions for few pages.
What we did is that we used URL rewrite to rewrite the pages to be more seo friendly.
Here is one example with one of our product pages:

Old format:

```
www.mysite.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=12345&SKU=44412-2212A
```

New format:

```
www.mysite.com/Products/12345-44412-2212a.aspx
```

What we are doing now, when someone will ask for `www.mysite.com/Products/12345-44412-2212a.aspx` they are taken to `www.mysite.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=12345&SKU=44412-2212A` but the URL still remains `www.mysite.com/Products/12345-44412-2212a.aspx`.

But if someone type in `www.mysite.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=12345&SKU=44412-2212A`, they will see exactly the same page as `www.mysite.com/Products/12345-44412-2212a.aspx` since the data on the page is same.

What I was thinking is to block `product.aspx` pages in *robots.txt* file, but I don't know if that automatically will block Google bots from crawling this page too `www.mysite.com/Products/12345-44412-2212a.aspx`, since that one is only URL rewritted page from the other page format, `www.mysite.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=12345&SKU=44412-2212A`.

What do you guys think, how can we tackle this problem, any advice, because GWT is reporting that I have duplicate meta description issue, and those are the pages reported as duplicate, I want to have only one page per product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or use 301 redirection to tell Google that your content has been move to the new URL.

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
header( "Location: http://www.exemple.com/new_clean_url" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `rel="canonical"`.

Open `www.mysite.com/Products/12345-44412-2212a.aspx` and put canonical in this page source (`<head>` section).

Link `rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/Products/12345-44412-2212a.aspx"`.

For more information regarding canonical: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394.